# How to get the non-named field value of data type in Haskell ? (How to get 'x' 'y' value from Rectangle in gtk2hs?)

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

`data Rectangle = Rectangle Int Int Int Int`  [(link to gtk2hs-doc)](http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/gtk2hs-docs-0.9.11/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#t:Rectangle)
I don't have any idea to get 'width' or 'height' values from `Rectangle`.
How to get the non-named field value of data type? Thanks.

---

For What:

I want to get the size of a widget and tried like this:

```
main = do
    initGUI
    -- . . . 
    widget <- drawingAreaNew
    canvasArea <- newIORef $ Rectangle 0 0 defaultWidth defaultHeight
    widget `onExpose` updateCanvas widget (liftIO (readIORef canvasArea) >>= render)
    onSizeAllocate widget $ updateSize canvasArea
    -- . . .

updateSize :: IORef a -> a -> IO ()
updateSize old new = writeIORef old new
```

And noticed that I don't know the way of getting the values...

Comment: Can you just pattern match on it?  `let (Rectangle x y w h) = myRectangle`

Comment: OK. I was lacked of elementary knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle behind getting those parameters out is pattern matching, like so:

```
case rect of
  Rectangle x y w h -> "The width is " ++ show w ++ " and the height is " ++ show h
```

This will assign the width and the height to `w` and `h` inside the case expression.

In a specific setting this could possibly be made shorter (by pattern matching directly on the argument to a function, by assigning the `rect` value to a pattern and so on) but pattern matching like this is the main principle.

Comment: Thank you! I've got it. I gonna play with haskell more and more.

Answer (score 1):

Better is to declare `Rectangle` somewhat different:

```
data Rectangle = Rectangle { left, top, width, height :: Int }
```

Then, if `r` is a `Rectangle`, you can write `width r` to get its width.

You can still write `Rectangle 100 200 300 400` to create a `Rectangle`.

Comment: It sounds nice! ..however I couldn't make it work.
I made library's Rectangle importing hidden. but it seems still callback function need for.
I don't know how to make type matched in right hand of 
    `onSizeAllocate widget $ updateSize canvasArea` (this is in my first post's code).

Comment: ghc says :     
```
Couldn't match type `Rectangle'   
                  with `Graphics.Rendering.Pango.Structs.Rectangle'  
    Expected type: IORef  
                       gtk-0.12.4:Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Structs.Allocation
      Actual type: IORef Rectangle
    In the first argument of `updateSize', namely `canvasArea'
    In the second argument of `onSizeAllocate', namely
      `(updateSize canvasArea)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      onSizeAllocate da (updateSize canvasArea)
```
`type Allocation = Rectangle` here.  
Would it be there are any nice solution?

Comment: sorry for broken layout.